# Get access to the device type GPU and CPU activation

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting

I would like to store and load the activation of CPU and GPU in the device types.
In the python console could I find this path:

```
bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.compute_device_type
```

This shows the device type but I can't find the access to the active GPU or CPU.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: @Robert Gützkow - I'm thinking you might be able to assist with this, based on your answer _here_ - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154510/how-to-select-all-non-cpu-cuda-or-non-cpu-opencl-devices-for-cycles-rendering-c. My knowledge of .bpy in this manner is rather limited, I'm afraid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting GPU with Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104651/selecting-gpu-with-python-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is in the cycles addon preferences.  As you know, access to the preferences for that addon can be found using `bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences`.

The cycles preference has a method `get_devices` that returns a list of tuples of `CyclesDeviceSettings`.  The information you want is in the tuples in the individual entries.  Here's some code that prints that information:

This, of course, is an undocumented API and may change from release to release.  This works for 2.93.6

```
import bpy

deviceList = bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.get_devices()
for deviceTuple in deviceList:
    print("Devices:")
    for device in deviceTuple:
        print(f"\t{device.name} ({device.type}) {device.use}")
```

It is left as an exercise for the reader to determine how the tuples are used.  On my machine in 2.93.6 The output from that script is

```
Devices:
    GeForce GTX 1070 (CUDA) True
    Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz (CPU) False
Devices:
    Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz (CPU) False
```

The relevant source can be found, with developer extras enabled, by right clicking on the fields with the red arrows and selecting "edit source" from the menu. It is, um, enlightening.